# ModelComparer does not work at all

Tags: gxt

I'm having problems with ModelComparer. Here is the code:

```
mycombobox.getStore().setModelComparer(new ModelComparer<BeanModel>() {

    @Override
    public boolean equals(BeanModel m1, BeanModel m2) {
        System.out.println("HEY.");
        if(m1 == null) return false;
        if(m2 == null) return false;
        return (((mycomboelement)m1.getBean()).getId()==((mycomboelement)m2.getBean()).getId());
    }
});
```

The ModelComparer I defined does not work at all. When I call

```
abeanmodel = mycombobox.getStore().findModel(x);
```

the variable `abeanmodel` is always `null`, neither the message "HEY." is printed on console. I can't figure out what's wrong. I'm using gxt-2.2.3. TIA.

Francesco

Comment: What is the return type of MyComboElement.getId()? String, int, some other object?

Comment: Sorry. I didn't mentioned it. It's an int.

Comment: I think you will need to post more code... 

Does this work? `abeanmodel = mycombobox.getStore().findModel("id", x.getId());`

Comment: Maybe I got the answer. The ModelComparer compare the given element against an empty Store. That's because of the Store.getLoader().load() asynchronous call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer. Terrel was right. I've to post some more code.
When I execute:

```
mycombobox.getStore().findModel(x);
```

I check my `BeanModel x` against an empty store. That's because of GWT's asynchronous call execution. To get the code working I have to implement a `LoadListener`:

```
mycombobox.getStore().getLoader().addLoadListener(new LoadListener(){
    @Override
public void loaderLoad(LoadEvent le) {
    abeanmodel = mycombobox.getStore().findModel(x);
}
});
```

now I'm sure to check my `BeanModel x` against a store filled with data.
I hope this helps. Thank you.

Francesco